# Limit selected option in bsmultiselect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bsmultiselect

I want to prevent the user to select more then 5 options, but I haven't found a solution yet. Can anyone help me, please?
Here is my code

```
student_html += '<select name="course_titles'+x+'[]" id="example" class="form-control mymultiple" multiple="multiple">';
student_html += strCourse;
student_html += '</select>';
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having, could you please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are possible two behaivours:

1. allow 6th selected but show it as invalid

Here are two different situations: is bsmultiselect is over the `select` (and results goes to form) or over the JS object.

In first case use "custom Html ValidationAPI" `multiSelect.validationApi.setCustomValidity(...)`;

In second case use "custom Bootstrap validation" (pass in the configuration `{getValidity: fuction( return true; //or false ) }` )

2. do not allow 6th selected at all

I this case pass the setSelected over the configuration and return false if you want to cancel the 6th element selection

```
{
  setSelected(){
    if (getSelectedCount(options) ==5) // write it getSelectedCount, just loop through your data or query bsMultiSelect.picksCount;
          return false;
  }
}
```